# error: cannot find symbol variable relativeLayout

Tags: android, gradle

I am getting an error when i run the project .I am attaching code from my java file and from the gradle console
Here is the code form the activity_funfacts.xml.There is a RelativeLayout tag here

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".FunFactsMyActivity"
    android:background="#ff51b46d">

    <TextView
        android:text="Did you know"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:textColor="#80ffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Aint strech it when they wake up in the morning"
        android:id="@+id/factTextView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="24dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show Another Fun Fact"
        android:id="@+id/showFactbButton"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Output from Gradle Console

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava
/Users/AndroidStudioProjects/FunFacts/app/src/main/java/com/example/funfacts/FunFactsMyActivity.java:29: error: cannot find symbol
        final RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
                                                                                ^
  symbol:   variable relativeLayout
  location: class id
1 error

 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.



  BUILD FAILED

Total time: 5.252 secs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define an id as `android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"` under your `RelativeLayout` tag.

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that you do not have the ID `relativeLayout` in your Layout XML file.

Please check that `R.layout.activity_funfacts` contains a `RelativeLayout` with the id `relativeLayout`.

Comment: more a question than an answer ?

Comment: @Blackbelt: True, improved answer.

Comment: @Knossos : Where can i find R.layout.activity_funfacts?

Comment: In your application directory, /res/layouts/

Comment: i edit the post with the code from  R.layout.activity_funfacts